# Tunnelblick can't load load net.tunnelblick.tun and/or net.tunnelblick.tap kexts

Tags: openvpn

**Description of the bug**
I'm using Tunnelblick 3.7.9beta02 (build 5200) on macOS Mojave version 10.14.2 (18C54). It was working just fine until I installed Sophos. So removed sophos, but the problem persists.

When I try to connect, the following error occurs.

```
Could not start OpenVPN (openvpnstart returned with status #247)

Contents of the openvpnstart log:
*Tunnelblick: openvpnstart log:
     Loading tun-signed.kext
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tun-signed.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tun-signed.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tun-signed.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tun-signed.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tun-signed.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     Unable to load net.tunnelblick.tun and/or net.tunnelblick.tap kexts in 5 tries. Status = 71
2019-02-11 18:42:29 *Tunnelblick: openvpnstart starting OpenVPN
```

Have searched this on forums and Tunnelblick website. None of the solutions worked. In fact, found no tun or tap kext by running kextstat.

**To Reproduce**
This started absolutely out of nowhere.

**Diagnostic information**
Got [these logs](https://pastebin.com/XdniqpWW) following [these instructions](https://tunnelblick.net/cBeforeYouPost.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got this solution from [Tunnelblick developer jkbullard](https://github.com/jkbullard).

In modern versions of macOS, there is almost never a good reason to use Tunnelblick's tun kexts. Allow Tunnelblick/OpenVPN to use the built-into-macOS "utun" driver instead, by removing or commenting out the following line in your OpenVPN configuration file:

```
 dev-type tun
```

(You must also **not** have "Always load Tun driver" set in the "Connecting & Disconnecting" tab of the "Advanced" settings window. The default, "Load Tun driver automatically" is usually the best setting.)